# How can I get selected row values of a DataGrid in C# and Hide a column from DataGrid?

Tags: c#, datagrid, smart-device

I am developing an smart device application on windows 6 smart device so DataGridView is not available. I want to get selected row cell values and hide some columns. Is it possible in DataGrid?

Comment: Please post some code on what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

For a single cell, you can use:

```
var cellInfo = dataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
```

This returns a DataGridCellInfo object containing the information of the selected cell.

To hide columns, you have to set their Visibility property to Visibility.Collapsed.

```
dataGrid.Columns[index].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Hope this helps!

But next time provide some code please.

Comment: First both your codes are not working as i dont find properties like
 dataGrid.SelectedCells and datagrid .Columns

Comment: Strange. Both codes work for me. Are you sure you are using a DataGrid object?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get all selected values from your DataGrid with this code, written in your window's `xaml.cs` file:

```
 var selectedItems = this.dataGrid1.SelectedItems;
```

Also, if you want to select always entire row, you have to change property of your `dataGrid`:

```
this.dataGrid1.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
```

And for hiding the columns you should change column's Visibility property to Collapsed:

```
this.dataGrid1.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CellClick Event of DataGridView to select a row in your datagrid and to show the values of the columns in the specified textboxes.

```
private void dgvUserList_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex!=-1)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvUserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());

            SqlConnection _sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString);

            if (_sqlconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || _sqlconnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                _sqlconnection.Close();
                _sqlconnection.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand _sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='" + id + "'");

            _sqlcommand.Connection = _sqlconnection;
            _sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter _sqldataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_sqlcommand);

            DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();

            _sqldataadapter.Fill(_datatable);

            foreach (DataRow _datarow in _datatable.Rows)
            {
                txtUsername.Text = _datarow["Username"].ToString();
                txtPassword.Text = _datarow["Password"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not using "DataGridVIew" I can only use DataGrid..
Well i found solution of one of my problem.. datagrid[datagrid.CurrentRowIndex,columnindex].ToString();